# Hive does not start: Error creating path /hive/cluster/delegation/METASTORE/keys

Tags: hadoop, hive

I ran into a problem on a kerberized cluster where hive would not start.

Symptoms:

- Services start succesfully (and did not stop)
- In Ambari an alert appeared which mentioned that the Hive metastore failed
- Starting hive on the command line did not succeed (it just kept hanging)
- Via beeline I was able to see metadata, but not get actual data

I found the following error in /var/log/hive/hivemetastore.log

```
2016-08-29 10:12:49,047 ERROR [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:main(5934)) - Metastore Thrift Server threw an exception...
org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.DelegationTokenStore$TokenStoreException: Error creating path /hive/cluster/delegation/METASTORE/keys
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.ZooKeeperTokenStore.ensurePath(ZooKeeperTokenStore.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.ZooKeeperTokenStore.initClientAndPaths(ZooKeeperTokenStore.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.ZooKeeperTokenStore.init(ZooKeeperTokenStore.java:469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server.startDelegationTokenSecretManager(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:6015)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5930)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$AuthFailedException: KeeperErrorCode = AuthFailed for /hive/cluster/delegation/METASTORE/keys
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:123)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:783)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$11.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:691)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$11.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:675)
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:672)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:453)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:443)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$3.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:257)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$3.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.ZooKeeperTokenStore.ensurePath(ZooKeeperTokenStore.java:160)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that I actually tried several things, so I am not sure whether this is the full solution, but here is the final step, which I believe to be the critical one:

After a long search I indirectly found this site: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/49040/hive-metastore-crashes-on-nullpointerexception-wit.html

Here is the relevant fragment that helped me resolve the issue:

> This is a known issue being tracked in the following Hortonworks bug:
>
> https://hortonworks.jira.com/browse/BUG-42602
>
> WORKAROUND:
>
> Set the hive.cluster.delegation.token.store.class to the following:
>
> hive.cluster.delegation.token.store.class=org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.DBTokenStore
>
> If using Ambari, this setting can be changed by clicking on the Hive
>   service on the Ambari Dashboard, navigating to the "Configs" tab, and
>   modifying the parameter in the "Advanced Hive-site" section of the
>   Hive configs. Save the changes and restart Hive from the Ambari User
>   Interface when prompted.
>
> If not using ambari, this setting can be located in the
>   /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml file.  Make sure this change is made on
>   all applicable nodes on the cluster.  Once the changes are made, the
>   Hive services must be restarted.